# Unable to Locate the Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

Recently, I received an Email regarding an issue in our Salesforce Production org. Error message:

> Error Occurred During Flow "PSA_Project_End_Date_Changed": The flow tried to update these records: null.
>
> The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: MyApexTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

There is no Flow by this name. When I searched this in FlowDefinition, I did find that with the same 'DeveloperName' and 'FullName'. But, when I look in Process Builder, there is no Process Builder by the name.

**Update**: Tried using Workbench. I found this in FLow Definition but couldn't locate this in Frontend(a place where I can see what it does).

Comment: Did you also check Flow in the setup menu? It could be a Process Builder or a Visual Flow.

Comment: Verify your flow once using workbench.You can find both flows and processes using Workbench:
Info => Metadata Types & Components => Flow for Flows
Info => Metadata Types & Components => FlowDefinition for Processes

Comment: I checked the Flows, only two other flows.

Comment: @sanketkumar I can see this under the FlowDefinition using the Workbench, but couldn't locate it in the frontend.

Comment: as far as CPU time over is concerned, this is probably because the trigger is being called infinitely. Used static flag to break the loop.

Comment: @sanketkumar I already used a recursion check. That part is covered.

Comment: can you once check the label for that particular flow.. may be some other label which is diffrent from  developer name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, what I found is that there is a *bug* in Salesforce due to which we're unable to see an active Process Builder Flow from Process Builder UI. This is what the Official Documentation said,

> This happens when the user first creates a Process Builder Flow, which in the background is really just a special type of flow and should never be accessed or modified via Visual Workflow Designer. In short, accessing Process Builder flow via Visual workflow designer will cause such issue.

The article also provided a workaround: [Unable to view active Process Builder Flow from Process Builder UI](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231232&language=en_US&type=1)